# SKOSXL crosswalk, RDF/XML to text

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf

I'm trying to create a crosswalk with the following skos file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:skosxl="http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#"
     xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:ns0="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrontology#"
     xmlns:ns1="http://art.uniroma2.it/ontologies/vocbench#"
     xmlns:void="http://rdfs.org/ns/void#"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">

 <skosxl:Label rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_en_1299502680191">
 </skosxl:Label>

 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.caas.net.cn/caas/cat/c_26474">
<skos:narrowMatch rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
 </rdf:Description>

 <skosxl:Label rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_pt_1299502680512">
 </skosxl:Label>

 <skosxl:Label rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_ja_1299502683986">
</skosxl:Label>

<skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26321">
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fa">آبیس ماریزی‌ای</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zh">大白叶冷杉</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="tr">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="th">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="sk">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ru">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pt">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hi">एबीस मैरीइसी</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pl">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="lo">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="it">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hu">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="de">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="cs">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ja">オオシラビソ、アオモリトドマツ</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ar">شوح ماريزي</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:broader rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
</skos:Concept>

<skosxl:Label rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_fa_1299502680235">
</skosxl:Label>

<skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_33272">
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ru">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pt">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ar">شوح نوميدي</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pl">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="lo">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="it">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hu">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="de">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="cs">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hi">एबीस न्यूमीडिका</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ja">アルゼリアモミ、アルジェリアモミ</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fa">آبیس نومیدیکا</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="tr">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zh">阿尔及利亚冷杉</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="th">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="sk">Abies numidica</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:broader rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
</skos:Concept>

<skosxl:Label rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_lo_1299502680439">
</skosxl:Label>

.....

<skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_1591">
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ar">أشجار عيد الميلاد</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="de">Weihnachtsbaum</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hu">karácsonyfa</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fa">درختان کریسمس</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="tr">yılbaşı ağacı</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pt">Árvore de Natal</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="it">Alberi di Natale</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pl">Choinka</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="cs">vánoční stromky</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zh">圣诞树</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="te">సరిగా వికసించని</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="lo">ຕົ້ນກຣິສມາດ</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">christmas trees</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="th">ต้นคริสต์มาส</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ko">크리스마스트리</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr">Arbre de noël</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="sk">vianočné stromčeky</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ru">новогодние елки</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hi">क्रिस्मस वृक्ष</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ja">クリスマスツリー</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Árboles de navidad</skos:prefLabel>
</skos:Concept>

<skosxl:Label rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_es_1299502680212">
</skosxl:Label>

<skosxl:Label rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_ko_1299502680404">
</skosxl:Label>

....

<skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_5886">
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="tr">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="th">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="sk">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ru">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pt">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pl">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="lo">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="it">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hu">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="cs">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="de">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fa">کاجیان</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ko">소나무과</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hi">पाइनेसी</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ar">صنوبريات (فصيلة)</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zh">松科</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ja">マツ科</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
</skos:Concept>

....


<skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10">
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="en">firs</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="zh">冷杉</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="hu">fenyõ</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="fa">نرادها</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="te">దేవదారు చెట్లు</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="cs">jedle (Abies)</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="hi">देवदार</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="zh">枞树</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="pl">Jodła</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="en">firsz</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="tr">göknar</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="fa">جنس نراد</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="hu">jegenyefenyő</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="tr">köknar</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="it">Abeti</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="de">Tanne</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="cs">jedle</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="ja">モミ類、モミ</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="es">Abeto (abies)</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="hi">फिर्स्ज</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="ru">пихта</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="fr">Sapin</skos:altLabel>
<skos:altLabel xml:lang="pt">Abeto</skos:altLabel>
<skos:broadMatch rdf:resource="http://www.caas.net.cn/caas/cat/c_39707"/>
<skos:broadMatch rdf:resource="http://www.caas.net.cn/caas/cat/c_39743"/>
<skos:broadMatch>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.caas.net.cn/caas/cat/c_9834">
    <skos:narrowMatch rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
  </rdf:Description>
 </skos:broadMatch>

<skos:broadMatch rdf:resource="http://www.caas.net.cn/caas/cat/c_36350"/>
<skos:broadMatch rdf:resource="http://www.caas.net.cn/caas/cat/c_26474"/>
<skos:broadMatch>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.caas.net.cn/caas/cat/c_6066">
    <skos:narrowMatch rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</skos:broadMatch>

<skos:broadMatch rdf:resource="http://www.caas.net.cn/caas/cat/c_43866"/>
<skosxl:prefLabel rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_en_1299502680191"/>
<skosxl:prefLabel rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_pt_1299502680512"/>
<skosxl:prefLabel>
  <skosxl:Label rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_hi_1299502680286">
  </skosxl:Label>
</skosxl:prefLabel>

....

<skosxl:altLabel rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_ja_1299502683986"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_34587"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_11"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26316"/>
<skos:narrower>
  <skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_1414489388571">
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="tr">Abies cilicica</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
  </skos:Concept>
</skos:narrower>

<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_17"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_16"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26321"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26320"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_13"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_12"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26318"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26317"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_18"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_33272"/>
<skos:narrower>
  <skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26323">
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zh">富士山冷杉</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ja">シラビソ、シラベ</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ar">شوح ويتشي</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="tr">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="th">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="sk">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ru">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pt">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pl">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="lo">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="it">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hu">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="de">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="cs">Abies veitchii</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fa">آبیس ویتکی‌ای</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hi">एबीस विट्ची</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
  </skos:Concept>
</skos:narrower>

...

<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_1322232213779"/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_19"/>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ar">شوح</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fa">آبیس</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ko">전나무속</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ja">モミ属</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="tr">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="th">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="sk">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ru">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pt">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pl">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="lo">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="it">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hu">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="de">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="cs">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hi">पलूदर</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zh">冷杉属</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:closeMatch>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://d-nb.info/gnd/4184405-1">
    <skos:closeMatch rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</skos:closeMatch>

<skos:closeMatch rdf:resource="http://d-nb.info/gnd/7544134-2"/>
<ns0:isUsedAs rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_7776"/>
<ns0:isUsedAs rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_1591"/>
<skos:broader rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_5886"/>
<skos:inScheme rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc"/>
<ns1:hasStatus rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Published</ns1:hasStatus>
<void:inDataset rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/void.ttl#Agrovoc"/>
<ns0:hasTaxonomicLevel>
  <skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_11125">
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ja">属</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="es">género (taxón)</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="cs">rod</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="pl">Genus</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="de">Genus</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ko">속</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ru">род</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zh">属类</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hi">वंश</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr">genre (taxon)</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fa">سرده</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="tr">cins</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="sk">genus</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">genus</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="it">Genere</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="hu">nemzettség</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="lo">ສະກຸນ (ດຽວ)</skos:prefLabel>
  </skos:Concept>
</ns0:hasTaxonomicLevel>

<dc:created rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2012-02-03T16:39:28Z</dc:created>
<dc:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2015-01-26T21:39:15Z</dc:modified>
</skos:Concept>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrontology#hasTaxonomicLevel">
<rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrontology#taxonomicRelationship"/>
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Has taxonomic level</rdfs:label>
</rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:skosxl="http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#"
     xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
     xmlns:ns0="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrontology#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:ns1="http://art.uniroma2.it/ontologies/vocbench#"
     xmlns:void="http://rdfs.org/ns/void#"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
     xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/mapping#">

.... (another one to process)

</rdf:RDF>
</root>
```

I want to output it into text like the one below:

```
=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500
=300  \\$ahttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10
=301  \\$abroader$ben$cAbies mariesii$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26321
=301  \\$abroader$ben$cAbies numidica$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_33272
=302  \\$aisusedas$ben$cchristmas tress$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_1591
=303  \\$anarrower$ben$cPinaceae$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_5886
=304  \\$aAltLabel$ben$cfirsz
=305  \\$anarower$ben$cAbies cilicica$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_1414489388571
=305  \\$anarrower$ben$cAbies veitchii$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26323
=306  \\$ahastaxonomixlevel$ben$cgenus
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bar$cشوح
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bfa$cآبیس
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bko$c전나무속
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bja$cモミ属
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$btr$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bth$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bsk$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bru$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bpt$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bpl$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$blo$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bit$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bhu$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bfr$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bes$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$ben$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bde$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bcs$cAbies
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bhi$cपलूदर
=306  \\$aInOtherLanguages$bzh$c冷杉属
```

I have below initially the xslt but I still need to configure it further:

```
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:skosxl="http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#"
xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
   <xsl:for-each select="rdf:RDF">
    <xsl:text>STARTHERE</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:Description/skos:narrowMatch" />
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:Description/skos:exactMatch" />
        <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="newline">
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
      </xsl:variable>



    <xsl:template match="skos:narrowMatch">
      <xsl:text>=300  \\$a</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" />
      <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="skos:exactMatch">
      <xsl:text>=300  \\$a</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" />
      <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="skos:Concept">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:prefLabel" />
        <xsl:text>=301  \\$a</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@xml:lang='en'" />
      <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>



    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the question is how do I create the second line of codes which are the outputs with an xslt, having the initial xslt above. Thanks in advance and cheers!

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What's the problem?

Comment: Also as a general remark: while it is perhaps possible to do what you need with XSLT, this kind of thing is typically far simpler if you use an RDF API  of some sort. There's toolkits available for pretty much any popular language.

Comment: Hi Jeen Broekstra, I wanted to out the rdf xml file into:       =LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500
=300  \\$ahttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10
=301  \\$abroader$ben$cAbies mariesii$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26321
=301  \\$abroader$ben$cAbies numidica$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_33272
=302  \\$aisusedas$ben$cchristmas tress$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_1591
=303  \\$anarrower$ben$cPinaceae$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_5886
=304  \\$aAltLabel$ben$cfirsz
=305  \\$anarower$ben$cAbies cilicica$dhttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_1414489388571
=305  \\$anarrower$ben$cAbies

Comment: I have actually was able to output the <skos:Concept><skos:prefLabel> in xml:lang='en' with the following: <xsl:template match="skos:Concept">
<xsl:for-each select="skos:prefLabel" />
<xsl:text>=301  \\$a</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="skos:prefLabel[@xml:lang='en']" />
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template> However, it captures them all node elements however it is not identified if it's broader or narrower term which can be ascertained by the sibling <skos:broader $ardf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/> That is now what I'm trying to figure out. TIA & cheers!

Comment: Thanks again Jeen Broekstra on the RDF API, I can consider that. But I need to study them further but I'm short of time I can only do it with XSLT because that's what I've been reading, and I saw you're the author of this [link] http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/model/vocabulary/SKOS.html  Cheers!

Comment: Rather than adding all this stuff in comments (which makes it practically unreadable), can you edit your question to add this information, properly formatted so it's readable?